# Laravel - select with relationship with one query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I have a Person model. Each person may have zero or more cars:

```
class Person extends Model
{
    public function cars()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Car');
    }
}
```

I wish to select and display all persons who have a ford with one running query. So i tried this:

```
$persons = Person::whereHas('cars', function ($query) {
    $query->where('mark', 'ford');
})->get();

foreach ($persons as $person) {
    foreach($person->cars()->get() as $car) {
        print $person->name . " has a " . $car->mark . $car->model
    } 
}
```

The $persons is gotten with one query, but inside the foreach loop $person->cars()->get() creates a new query for each person. How can i avoid this and get the needed car data with the first query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the `mark` filter to `whereHas()` and `with()`:

```
$persons = Person::whereHas('cars', function ($query) {
    $query->where('mark', 'ford');
})->with(['cars' => function($query) {
    $query->where('mark', 'ford');
}])->get();
```

Comment: It should be added that when using `whereHas` as above, only `Persons` with a Ford will be in the resulting collection. And also the query will only eager load the related Ford cars for these persons. If you want to eager load all cars for them and not only Fords, you should remove the sub query from the `with` statement and only use `with('cars')`.

Comment: That's what the OP was asking for.

Comment: Actually, he didn't specify that he only wants cars of the brand Ford, but only persons with a Ford. Yet I agree, most likely he meant what you wrote. And please don't see my comment as criticism, it is just additional info for whoever it may concern. :)

Comment: He specified it in the comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/49564111/4848587 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in `cars()`

Use the below given snippet

```
foreach ($persons as $person) {
     foreach($person->cars as $car) 
       { 
         print $person->name . " has a " . $car->mark . $car->model
        } 
      }
```

When u do `cars()` it refers to model which execute another query. But when u use `cars` it only refers to collection which is already loaded.

Hope this helps

Comment: I am currently on a mobile app so forget about indentation of code.

Comment: The main problem was that i needed to add with() with a filter because i wasn't loading the cars at all. But the second part was indeed that i used cars() so your answer is also correct and helped. Thank you! :)

Comment: @user1985273 Yess for sure you have to use `with()`

Answer (score 0):

it is worth examining : [laravel Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

When used in this manner will come in a query relational data.

Example:

```
Person::with('cars')->get();
```

This code response:
Person data with Person's Car data

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed give me the result with one query, but if i try to  iterate $person->cars the collection has all the cars, not only fords as i would expect. Any idea about that?