# Eloquent, model has many but not directly related

Tags: php, eloquent

can't get my head around this one! I was using attributes however this was causing multiple queries running rather than **one**.

I have got many **locations**, which all have their own set of **social media** and **contact** data. My social media and contact data is stored in it's own table, these tables also link to a table with information about the type of data.

So, as an example.

**locations**

```
id      name      full_name
1       'Test'    'Testing'
```

**location_contact**

```
id      content     type_id     location_id
1      '4532432'       3            1
```

**contact_types**

```
id      value      link
3    'telephone'  'tel:'
```

A location could have multiple of the same contact types, so I need to group them all within the contact type. So my expected data would be:

```
[
    0 => [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Test',
        'full_name' => 'Testing',
        'contact' => [
            'telephone' => [
                'id' => 3,
                'value' => 'telephone',
                'link' => 'tel:',
                'data' => [
                    0 => [
                        'id' => 1,
                        'content' => 4532432,
                        'type_id' => 3,
                        'location_id' => 1
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

How would I go about doing this? Or would it be easier to manipulate the data once it has been retrieved with just 1 query?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49563701/laravel-select-with-relationship-with-one-query   `$locations = App\Locations::with(['location_contact', 'contact_types'])->get();`

Comment: That's not going to give me my expected data...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reviewing the design of your relationships. All the same, I suggest you use relationships and mutators on the Location model.

On the Locations model:

```
protected $appends = ['contact'];

public function getContactAttribute(){
    $res = [];
    $res['telephone'] = $this->contactTypes[0];
    $res['telephone']['data'] = $this->contacts;

    return $res;
}

public function contactTypes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany("App\ContactType", 'location_contact', 'location_id', 'type_id');
}

public function contact()
{
    return $this->hasMany("App\ContactType", 'location_id');
}
```